# How Make a Sprite Node Rotate Around Another Node? (One More Line)

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit

So, I am trying to challenge my self by recreating the popular App Store game, ***One More Line*** using SpriteKit and Swift 3; however, I am immediately having a big issue.

1)How do I get my node to rotate around another node when the user is tapping

2) I want my node to continue moving in the same direction it is facing when the user releases their finger (hope that makes sense...).

kinda like this

[image]

In my GameScene.sks I created a center node that is constantly rotating and a player. Then I did this:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    player.move(toParent: center)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    player.move(toParent: self)
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    let dx = 5 * cos(player.zRotation)
    let dy = 5 * sin(player.zRotation)
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy))

}
```

player moves to the right and when I tap it circles around the node, when I release it continues to move to the right.

[image]

I know that I am going about this all wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which bit is not right? Is the moving in the circle OK but the movement when you stop touching wrong?

Comment: Yeah, when I let go it just moves right, it doesn't retain the direction it is facing. It's also moving closer to the center node I don't want that, but I think I can fix that by stopping the impulse when it's a child of the center node.

Comment: Is there any way that I can use an SKPhysicsJointLimit? That way I wouldn't need to make it a child of the center node?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you are looking for, but if you simply want a sprite to rotate evenly around a centre sprite, add the centre sprite, another centre sprite (invisible) and add your outer sprite to the invisible centre sprite. Then rotate your two centre sprites. Adjust the outerObject's x position to bring the outerObject closer or further from the centre object.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        let centerObject = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blue, size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
        addChild(centerObject)

        let invisibleParent = SKSpriteNode()
        addChild(invisibleParent)

        let outerObject = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        outerObject.position.x = 100
        invisibleParent.addChild(outerObject)

        centerObject.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: 1, duration: 1)))
        invisibleParent.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -1, duration: 1)))

    }    

}
```

[image]